# Quadratic equation for a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have the quadratic equation
$$
\hat{f}^2+\hat{B}\hat{f}+\hat{C}=0
$$
for the matrix $\hat{f}$, where $\hat{B}$, $\hat{C}$ are some known matrices. *Do any general methods of its solution exist?*

To be more specific, in my case $\hat{B}$ is the infinite diagonal matrix with the elements $B_{nm}=\delta_{nm}(i\varepsilon+b[n+\frac12])$, $i$ is the imaginary unit, and $\hat{C}$ is proportional to the unit matrix: $C_{nm}=\delta_{nm}c$. *Should the matrix $\hat{f}$ be only diagonal in this case?*

**Update**
I have found the related questions [Is there a unique solution for this quadratic matrix equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95981/is-there-a-unique-solution-for-this-quadratic-matrix-equation?rq=1) and [Solve $AX^2 + BX + C = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2519480/solve-ax2-bx-c-0?noredirect=1&lq=1) about general solutions of quadratic matrix equations, so now my question is simpler: *if $\hat{B}$ is a diagonal matrix and $\hat{C}$ is proportional to the unit matrix, so is it true that $\hat{f}$ should be also diagonal matrix, or there exist some nondiagonal solutions?*

Comment: In general you have symbolically $2f= -B\pm\sqrt{B^2-4C}$.  The problem is that, unlike, for example, the function $f (x) = e ^ x$ with which $f (M) = e ^ M$ always makes sense, the same does not happen with the function $f (x) =\sqrt{B^2-4C}$  because not always $B ^ 2-4C$ is the square of a matrix (this is called symbolic calculation in algebras where it is said that the numerical function $ f$ operates in the algebra (All analytic function operates in a certain algebra of harmonic analysis and the reciprocal of this theorem is a famous difficult result of Katznelson).

Comment: @Piquito , that you write is absolutely false. 1. The relation $(2f+B)^2=B^2-4C$ is true almost only when $BC=CB$. 2. Generically $B^2-4C$ is invertible and has distinct eigenvalues; thus it admits $2^n$ complex square roots. Conclusion. If $BC=CB$, then generically, there are $2^n$ solutions. 3. It's false if $BC\not= CB$; in this case, there are generically $\binom{2n}{n}$ complex solutions.

Comment: Read better your Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\trace}[0]{\text{trace}}$Consider this:
$$
X =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}, 
B =
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 0\\
0 & -2
\end{bmatrix},
C =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
X^{2} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},
$$
and
$$
X^{2} + B X + C = 0.
$$

---

More generally, if $X$ is *any* $2 \times 2$ matrix, then $X$ is a root of its characteristic polynomial, so that
$$
X^{2} + B X + C = 0,
$$
where $B$ and $C$ are the scalar matrices
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}
- \trace(X) & 0\\
0 & -\trace(X)
\end{bmatrix},
\qquad
C =
\begin{bmatrix}
\det(X) & 0\\
0 & \det(X)
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Thank you! But what about my specific case, where the matrices are generally of infinite size (although can be truncated to a finite size for a practical treatment), and $B$ is not proportional to the unit matrix, in contrast to your example?